# Outlook does not try to connect after system wake up

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook-2013

Usually I minimize my Outlook 2013 in system tray and it works well, but after I sleep my PC and later wake it up, the connectivity of my Outlook turns to be "DISCONNECTED", then I have to re-launch it to solve this problem. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to just toggle Work Offline <kbd>Alt</kbd>><kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>W</kbd>

[image: Work offline mode]

When you toggle it off it will tell outlook to disconnect when you toggle it back on it will tell outlook to try and reconnect to the server

This is not a perfect solution but <kbd>Alt</kbd>><kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>><kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>W</kbd> is a lot quicker then re-initializing outlook

Comment: I could verify by looking at the status bar: DISCONNECTED> WORKING OFFLINE > CONNECTED TO: MICROSOFT EXCHANGE. The connection seemed to be restored. Unfortunately after one minute the status went back to: DISCONNECTED. Toggling did not solve the connection issue for me but is a good way to force a re-connect. Gonna try to create new Outlook profile: [Resolve Outlook password prompt issue](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/resolve-outlook-password-prompt-issue/)